# Cannot create an object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.SanitizerProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack, htmleditorextender

I wanna use the HtmlEditorExtender from newest ajaxToolkit.
I have installed it and have configured it correctly in the web.config

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </sectionGroup>  
</configSections>  

<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
    <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
    </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

I cant compile the solution. Following error appears if I use the sanitizer-attribute provider in the htmlEditorExtender: SanitizerProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"

> Error-Message: Cannot create an object of type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.SanitizerProvider' from its string
>   representation 'HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider' for the
>   'SanitizerProvider' property.

If I dont use this attribute I can compile it but cant input `<br>` in the related textbox, because the sanitation removes it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my HtmlEditorExtender, took ages to get it working but this is how mine looks:

First of all I had the wrong version of the ajax control so I downloaded the latest version 4.5 from here
https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091

Then I added the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll and the HtmlAgilityPack.dll to my References (I am using visual studio 2010 by the way)

And added the following line of code to my web config:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web">
  <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

AND

```
<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"/>
  </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

It looks as if we have the same web config attributes, but my problem was i had an old version of the toolkit and had problems with the agility pack and the way the ajax website told me to add it to the web config wasnt working so i got the latest version i could find after a lot of google searching, and added those to my web config and it worked, let me know if this works